# How to show a button when item is selected in WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF datagrid that has two associated buttons for editing and deleting data. Ideally, I'd like to disable or make these buttons invisible when an item is not selected in the grid. How do I approach this?

If it matters my datagrid XAML is:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="10,174,12,35" Name="dataGridArchiveQueue" Visibility="Visible" AlternatingRowBackground="#01000000" BorderBrush="#FF688CAF" 
                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#37000000" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#37000000" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemArchiveGrid}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                              <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                                         Color="LightBlue" />
                        </DataGrid.Resources>

                    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataTrigger on button to handle the disable/visible of buttons OR you can write the logic on CanExecuteChange event of command which gets binded to button

**Data Trigger**

> ```
>         <Button.Style>
>             <Style>
>                 <Style.Triggers>
>                     <DataTrigger Binding="{SelectedItemArchiveGrid}" Value="{x:Null}">
>                         <Setter Property="IsEnabled"Value="False"></Setter>
>                     </DataTrigger>
>                 </Style.Triggers>
>             </Style>
>         </Button.Style>
> ```

**Command**

```
> public RelayCommand<object> DeletCommand { get; set; }
> 
> DeletCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnDelete, OnDeletCanExecute);
> 
> private void OnDelete(object obj) { }
> 
> private bool OnDeletCanExecute(object obj)  {
     return SelectedItemArchiveGrid != null;  }
```

**XAML**

```
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Delete Command}"/>
```

Comment: Although the property exists I'm receiveing the error "Cannot resolve sysmbol 'SelectedItemArchiveGrid' in my XAML? Any idea why?

Comment: 'SelectedItemArchiveGrid' is not a property of DataView or DataTable and you need to Relative Source on binding in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can [change the Data Template for the Currently Selected Item](http://codingcontext.wordpress.com/2008/09/28/changing-the-data-template-for-the-currently-selected-item/).